# After uploading into cpanel Laravel 5.3 throwing InvalidArgumentException error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

After Developing a test App using Laravel 5.3, When I uploaded to the Cpanel it throwing Invalid exception Error. According to error message the App looking for some files from my local PC.Even after clearing all files from ***Storage\framwork\session***    it behaves alike previous.

App link:  http://autocomplete.bappasarkar.info/

**NB:** After first time uploading the app threw an error

> The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC

Then I generate key by the artisan command

> "php artisan key:generate"

After generating key when the App uploaded for the second time , it's throwing the current Error.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have permissions issue, the following commands are for *nix based OS's.
Try

`sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache`

`sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`

Comment: Dear,Thank you for response. I am sorry to say that I have uploaded the App to a shared hosting  where I have only the cpanel's username and pass. Have any way to handle it from cpanel or from local PC?

Comment: You have terminal in cpanel, go to your project root and run the above commands

Comment: Sorry my c panel has no terminal option activated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permission through ftp or file manager from Cpanel.